# VBScript MsgBox always reports false. What library do I need installed on the computer?

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to get my VBScript to report the proper value of a clicked button in a Message Box.

```
intAnswer =  Msgbox("Enter Data", _
        4, "Answer")
msgbox(intAnswer)
If intAnswer = 6 Then
    Msgbox "You answered yes."
ElseIf intAnswer = 7 Then
    Msgbox "You answered no."
ElseIf intAnswer = 2 Then
    MsgBox "Cancelled."
End If
```

But, that first `msgbox(intAnswer)` always reports "False."  It's never the VBScript constants I am expecting, so I never get any of the If Then Else statements.

I have tried `vbYesNo` instead of just `4`.  I thought they constant definitions might not be on the server, but it does not matter.

What am I doing wrong?  How can I get my `msgbox` response to be a constant?

edit:  this is a vbscript running on the command line a .vbs file (or double-click it from explorer).

edit:  I have tried `cint(intanswer)` but I get the same result zero `0` in this case.

**edit:  further test reveals it only occurs on the server.  the local machine works just fine.**

Comment: Is this in a web page, a vbs file or something else?  How is `intAnswer` declared, a variant or an integer? The code works fine in VB for what it's worth (that is, if I click "Yes", it messages "6", then "You answered yes.")

Comment: It is not declared anyway except dim intAnswer.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables works good on a local machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found extraneous code.  It was a simple error.  Removed it.  All is well.

Comment: Don't forget to mark this [answer as accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) to show that the issue has been resolved.